# Manipulating DOM elements within a React component

Tags: reactjs

My code fetches a blob of HTML and renders it on the page. When the user selects some text within this blob, I want the selected text to be wrapped in its own span. (This is a "highlighting" feature similar Google Docs' comments system.)

If I were doing this with plain Javascript, I'd mutate the DOM on my own. But I'm not sure how to do this safely in React or where in the component lifetime I'd be able to do so.

Ideally, I could directly manipulate the `Element` corresponding to my HTML blob and use that directly within `render()`, but I don't know if this would play well with React's bookkeeping.

How can I do this in React without shooting myself in the foot?

**EDIT:**

Per request, some sample code. Let's say that our component receives these props:

```
{
  id: 1337,
  content: "<p>This is a paragraph with some <strong>markup</strong></p>",
  highlights: [],
}
```

And renders something accordingly:

```
const Widget = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.content}} />       
  },
});
```

Now the component is updated with `highlights: [{ start: 5, end: 10 }]`. I want to have chars 5 through 10 wrapped in some `<span>`.

Is the right way to do this to just parse `this.props.content` as an `Element`, add the `<span>` in the right place, and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` at the end?

Comment: Using `refs` whould work.  However, some sample code would help clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store your `<p>` element with the text you want to highlight in your state. Like

```
this.state = {
  willHighlight: <p>This is a <span>paragraph</span> with some <strong>markup</strong></p>
}
```

And then you can conditionaly render it. I think this is a better approach